# What is the probability of a random COVID antigen test detecting someone with symptoms

Tags: probability

I am trying to figure out the probability of an individual (let's call him Bob) returing a positive covid antigen result if he is a member of a group of 100 people being tested in groups of about 12 over 8 weeks.

Facts:

- The Antigen test is most reliable for 5 days from when symptoms are
  first displayed.
- Symptoms are first displayed after 4 or 5 days of
  being infected.
- 100 people are being tested in groups over 8 weeks
  on working days only.
- Each person only gets tested once in that period

The question is: What is the probablility of Bob returning a positive result for his test?

**EDIT: I'll try to add more information (assumptions) here...**

If somebody gets the virus, they would normally recover after 14 days.
The antigen test is only likely to return a positive result for this person when the viral load is greatest which from day 5 until day 10 of the infection.

So the probability of the antigen test giving a positive result for somebody infected is 5/14 (the 14 days is probably irrelevant)

Let's make the assumption that Bob does actually get infected at some point during the 8 week testing period.

In the 8 weeks, Bob would only get tested on working days. That's 40/56.

Working days on which he could be tested = 40/56
Days on which he could test positive if he had the virus 5/56

So do I now multiply these two numbers 40x5 / 56x56?
That would be approx 1/16

**Where I think this may be wrong:**
Weekends are obviously 2 says. Does it make any difference on which day Bob  gets infected. Let's say he gets it on a Saturday. The Antigen test would detect the virus from Thursday. He could be tested positive on Thursday, Friday or Monday. Does that make any difference to the 40/56 days? Should I be taking the 14 days of infection into account?

What about the days that he would test negative - does that have any influence on the maths?

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Is Bob infected/what are the chances that Bob is infected? What are the chances of getting a positive test if you're infected (during the 5 day period and after that)? What are the chances of a false positive? Why are we working in a group of 100 people, their tests don't influence the test result of Bob? I don't believe that  there currently isn't a reasonable answer to this question, without wild assumptions.

Comment: There is literally not enough information, we don't even know the success probability of the test or what percent of the population is infected

Comment: To add to the chorus, there is not even close to enough information to compute a probability here. It would be like asking, "what are the odds that someone in my household will stub their toe tomorrow given that there are 4 of us and 37 corners."

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I've edited the question making a few assumptions in the hope that you can help me out.

Comment: There is still close to no information given in your statement, the answer really can be anything in $[0,1]$ right now.

Comment: Everyone is telling me that there is not enough information... could anyone help define what you would need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, your question does not give enough information to answer the question. I will try to give an answer that encompasses a few different interpretations, and hopefully makes it clearer which information is needed to give an exact answer to the problem.

As I understand your post, the testing setup is as follows:

- If a person is infected on day $n$, they will return a positive antigen test on days $n+5, n+6, \ldots, n+10$ if they are tested on any of those days, and will otherwise get a negative result. (Perhaps you meant "day $5$" to be four days after "day $1$", the date of infection? It doesn't really affect the results, though.)
- Bob will be tested exactly once over an $8$-week period, and the date of the test will be selected uniformly at random from one of the $40$ weekdays in that period.

The above setup is enough for us to assess the probability that Bob will receive a positive antigen test, *if we know the probability of infection on a given day*. Without this information, it is impossible to give an answer: if Bob does not plan to interact with another human being during the 8-week period, his probability of a positive test is effectively zero, and if he deliberately times his infection to overlap with an entire work week, his probability could be as high as $5/40=1/8$. (It cannot be higher than this, if he only  gets infected once.) Again, to re-emphasize, **you need to specify the probability Bob gets infected on a given day** if you want this problem to have a well-defined answer.

---

Suppose that we are given such a series of probabilities for each day: $p_i$ is the chance of infection on day $i$.

If we start our numbering of the eight weeks with Monday as day $0$, and the final Sunday as day $55$, then the chance of being tested on day $n$ is

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
\frac1{40} & n\equiv 0,1,2,3,4 \pmod{7}\\
0 & n\equiv 5,6 \pmod{7}
\end{cases}$$

The chance of being at a stage of infection to return a positive result if tested on day $n$ is

$$p_{n-5}+p_{n-6}+\ldots+p_{n-10}$$

Then, we can compute

$$P(\text{positive test on day $n$}) = P(\text{gets tested on day $n$}) \cdot P(\text{positive test on day $n$}\ |\ \text{gets tested on day $n$}) $$
$$= f(n)\cdot (p_{n-5}+\ldots+p_{n-10})$$

Now, because we know that there is at most one positive result, the total probability of a positive result is just the expected number of positive results, or the sum of the probabilities of a positive test on each day (by linearity of expectation). If there were more than one test given over the 8-week period, the calculations would be somewhat more involved.

So our total probability is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{55}\left(f(n)\sum_{i=n-10}^{n-5}p_i\right)$$

You state in your post

> Let's make the assumption that Bob does actually get infected at some point during the 8 week testing period.

If we interpret this as meaning that $p_i=\frac1{56}$ for all $i$ from $0$ to $55$, and $p_i=0$ otherwise, then the the probability turns out to be $\frac3{28}\approx 0.107143$.

If we interpret this as meaning that $p_i=\frac1{61}$ for all $i$ from $-10$ to $50$, and $0$ otherwise (i.e. Bob is infected at a random day from among the days where he might be detected by an antigen test at some point during the testing period), then the resulting probability is $\frac{261}{2440}\approx 0.10697$. (These numbers are not very different, which should be expected since the setups are quite similar.)

---

However, note that our model of choosing the probability of infection on each day separately is a little misleading. If we ignore the relatively small chance of reinfections over the course of the $8$-week period, then it probably makes more sense to think about the probability $q_i$ that Bob is exposed to a source that *would have* infected him if he were susceptible, but will do nothing if he has already been infected. Furthermore, let's suppose that Bob has some initial chance $q'$ of having been exposed already on day $0$.

Then, we can obtain our series of $p_i$s from this: the chance of getting infected on day $i$ is the probability of exposure $q_i$, multiplied by the combined probabilities of not being exposed on day $0$ and of avoiding exposure each previous day. So we have

$$p_i = q_i\cdot (1-q')\cdot\prod_{j=0}^{i-1}(1-q_j)$$

(We can use a similar formula if we want to model this from an earlier starting point before day $0$.)

---

I have written some simple Python code [here](https://repl.it/@harrypotter5777/ConventionalThoseArraylist#main.py), which you can modify to customize some of the assumptions in the problem. I am still not sure exactly what the question you want to answer is, but I hope that this will help you in pursuit of it.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for an awesome answer.